# Node.js Showing JSON File in the Browser

Tags: json, node.js, browser

Using node.js I am attempting to load a .json file (file) and have it viewed on a web browser. So far I have been able to create a JSON object (obj) and viewed the JSON string of that object on the web browser. However, when I attempt to load the file I get the file link and not the file itself. Below is the code:

```
var jf = require('jsonfile');
var jsonfn = function(request, response) {

    var file = '/home/ubuntu/public/json/foods.json';
    var obj = {name: 'JP'};

    jf.writeFile(file, obj, function(err) {
    console.log(util.inspect(jf.readFileSync(file)));
    })
    response.json(obj);
};
```

Can anyone provide advice for me being able to load a JSON file and create a response to allow me to view the file in the web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jf.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
  if (err) return response.send(500);
  response.json(obj);
});

// or ...

require('fs').readFile(file, function(err, data) {
  if (err) return response.send(500);
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  response.send(data);
});
```